# Connection to Windows Phone 8 device or emulator failed (Emulator installation failed during the installation process)?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8 development

This is my system config
I am using Windows 8.1 pro

**This is my Hardware Config**

Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5700 @ 3.00GHz 3.00Ghz
Installed memory(RAM) : 4.00 GB
System Type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

And to enable emulator i tried many ways in But Failed.

**This is my CoreInfo**

[image]

And I referred [This Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

But I got this as response:

[image]

**and this one when I Run Machine Status Check**

[image]

Is there Any way to do Windows Phone 8 application development on this type of system?

If I use VMWare, Can I get out this error?

Comment: Did you try enabling hardware visualization from the BIOS?

Comment: Try downloading Intel Processer Identification utility from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=7838&lang=eng). See whether your CPU supports hardware virtualisation. If so, you can go to this [link](http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios) to enable hardware VT. Just try it and let me know

Comment: Thanks Yous Sahan Sir, I enabled hardware virtualisation(already enabled) But i dont Know what will be the Problem. and At this http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios 3rd step what is that. i am Using windows 8.1 Please help me sir..

Comment: Thank you Pantelis sir,Andrew Counts sir and Sahan Sir.. Please UP Vote The Question This may Helpful to other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CPU does not support SLAT so there is no way to install the emulator.
[Your CPU Specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/42801/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5700-2M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

[image]

Comment: The requirements for the Windows 8 phone emulator are pretty strict, and your processor does not meet the requirements.  I also had the same issue on a machine running a Q8400 quad core cpu.

Comment: So what should i need to do sir, Can i use VM ware or i Must Buy a New PC

Comment: using a virtual machine on top of your OS won't make features that aren't available on your processor appear, plus you can't run the emulator in an emulator anyway.  Buying a system with a better processor is your only option.

Comment: Yup, you'd need a new processor supporting the Extended Page Tables technology for intel processors and the equivalent for AMD. You can still develop with the Windows Phone 8 SDK, but you can only test apps on a device.